# DJango channels subscribe to multiple events

Tags: django, django-channels, stockquotes

I have django application with channels. It opens websocket connection to Crypto-market data provider. I received tick data, I insert those ticks in the database.

I also want to send that tick data to other application (say frontend). But I am not able to it efficiently.

Currently only single frontend application is present. So when it connects to django channels, I add that connection to group named('root') and send all the market-tick data to that group.

So the problem here is, If I decide to connect second frontend application, I get all the data that first user was requesting (as both clients are present in group 'root' on django).

I tried a method were when a users requests data for particular crypto, then I added him to that crypt-named group (if user want bitcoin data only, I added him to bitcoin group)
But I get lots crpto-data on django server and very big number of ticks per second. It feels kind of slow to send each tick data to that particular crypto group channel ( on tick check symbol and forward that tick to that symbol-named django channel).

Any suggestion on how to approach to this problem.?

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to channels groups from anywhere in your Django code

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("root", {'messages' : message, 'type' : 'chat_message'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by subscribing to topics from frontend application. Subscribing to topics is something spring websocket provides using STOMP.
However, in python i did not find any such utility.
I did below to solve this.

1. Every frontend application send list of topics to which it is interested.
2. In consumer, add these topics in scope variable.

```
# Receive message from WebSocket
   def receive_json(self, content):
       message = content.get("message")
       topics = content.get("topics")
       if topics:
           self.topics = topics
```

3. Now, when you send anything to group, you should always send with topic. For eg.

```
async_to_sync(channels.layers.get_channel_layer().group_send)('my_group_name',
  {"type": "notify.message", "message": message, "topic": topic}
)
```

4. Now, when Channels call `def notify_message` of consumer, you should check if received topic is in subscribe topic list or not. If yes, send it.

```
# Receive message from room group
   def notify_message(self, event):
       topic = event.get('topic')
       if topic not in self.topics:
           return
       message = event["message"]
       # Send message to WebSocket
       self.send_json({"message": message})
```

5. This way, you send data to client only to subscribed topics. You can always change topic subscription of connected client just by sending data from client to server.

I hope this helps.